# Is the behaviour of std::get on rvalue-reference tuples dangerous?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue-reference, stdtuple

The following code:

```
#include <tuple>

int main ()
{
  auto f = [] () -> decltype (auto)
  {
    return std::get<0> (std::make_tuple (0));
  };

  return f ();
}
```

(Silently) generates code with undefined behaviour - the temporary rvalue returned by `make_tuple` is propagated through the std::get<> and through the decltype(auto) onto the return type. So it ends up returning a reference to a temporary that has gone out of scope. See it here https://godbolt.org/g/X1UhSw.

Now, you could argue that my use of `decltype(auto)` is at fault. But in my generic code (where the type of the tuple might be `std::tuple<Foo &>`) I don't want to always make a copy. I really do want to extract the exact value or reference from the tuple.

My feeling is that this overload of `std::get` is dangerous:

```
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
constexpr std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple<Types...> >&& 
get( tuple<Types...>&& t ) noexcept;
```

Whilst propagating lvalue references onto tuple elements is probably sensible, I don't think that holds for rvalue references.

I'm sure the standards committee thought this through very carefully, but can anyone explain to me why this was considered the best option?

Comment: *"I don't think that holds for rvalue references"* - It does if you `forward_as_tuple`. You want the value category preserved. Or if you want to extract one value from a functions return value.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really sure that it is preserving the value category. For example, if I have a function returning a `std::tuple<int>` and I call `std::get<0>` on it I would expect to get a plain `int`, not an `int&&`. Can you give me a concrete example where you'd want something else?

Comment: Isn’t this overload of `get` needed for effective structured bindings?

Comment: I'm certainly willing to be convinced, but examples I've tried with a "safe" version of the overload (which just returns the unadorned `tuple_element` type when passed an rvalue reference tuple) seem to work fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
void consume(foo&&);

template <typename Tuple>
void consume_tuple_first(Tuple&& t)
{
   consume(std::get<0>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)));
}

int main()
{
    consume_tuple_first(std::tuple{foo{}});
}
```

In this case, we know that `std::tuple{foo{}}` is a temporary and that it will live for the entire duration of the `consume_tuple_first(std::tuple{foo{}})` expression.

We want to avoid any unnecessary copy and move, but still propagate the temporarity of `foo{}` to `consume`.

The only way of doing that is by having `std::get` return an *rvalue reference* when invoked with a temporary `std::tuple` instance.

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lBmOEAk9sqsA1s1c)

---

Changing `std::get<0>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))` to `std::get<0>(t)` produces a compilation error (as expected) ([**on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zzFmuyBDiwI51erQ)).

---

Having a `get` alternative that returns by value results in an additional unnecessary move:

```
template <typename Tuple>
auto myget(Tuple&& t)
{
    return std::get<0>(std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

template <typename Tuple>
void consume_tuple_first(Tuple&& t)
{
   consume(myget(std::forward<Tuple>(t)));
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y40AgJqJtl7PMife)

---

> but can anyone explain to me why this was considered the best option?

Because it enables optional generic code that seamlessly propagates temporaries *rvalue references* when accessing tuples. The alternative of returning by value might result in unnecessary move operations.

Comment: Ah I see. So my "safe_get" which returns the unadorned type causes an extra move. IMHO that would be a price worth paying for safety, but I can at least see it's debatable. Many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is dangerous and quite sad since it defeats the purpose of the ["most important `const`"](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/):

> Normally, a temporary object lasts only until the end of the full expression in which it appears. However, C++ deliberately specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself, and thus avoids what would otherwise be a common dangling-reference error.

In light of the quote above, for many years C++ programmers have learned that this was OK:

```
X const& x = f( /* ... */ );
```

Now, consider [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/evn4YqY1d):

```
struct X {
    void hello() const { puts("hello"); }
    ~X() { puts("~X"); }
};

auto make() {
    return std::variant<X>{};
}

int main() {
    auto const& x = std::get<X>(make()); // #1
    x.hello();
}
```

I believe anyone should be forgiven for thinking that line #1 is OK. However, since `std::get` returns a reference to an object that is going to be destroyed, `x` is a dangling reference. The code above outputs:

```
~X
hello
```

which shows that the object that `x` binds to is destroyed before `hello()` is called. Clang gives a warning about the issue but gcc and msvc don't. The same issue happens if (as in the OP) we use `std::tuple` instead of `std::variant` but, sadly enough, clang doesn't issues a warning for this case.

A similar issue happens with `std::optional` and this `value` overload:

```
constexpr T&& value() &&;
```

[This code](https://godbolt.org/z/96K6jzTne), which uses the same `X` above, illustrates the issue:

```
auto make() {
    return std::optional{X{}};
}

int main() {
    auto const& x = make().value();
    x.hello();
}
```

The output is:

```
~X
~X
hello
```

Brace yourself for more of the same with C++23's `std::except` and its methods `value()` and `error()`:

```
constexpr T&& value() &&;
constexpr E&& error() && noexcept;
```

I'd rather pay the price of the move explained in [Vittorio Romeo's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47905739/1137388). Sure, I can avoid the issue by removing `&` from lines #1 and #2. My point is that the rule for the "most important `const`" just became more complicated and we need to consider if the expression involves `std::get`, `std::optional::value`, `std::expected::value`, `std::expected::error`, ...

Comment: "*just became more complicated*" If by "just", you mean eleven years ago when C++11 came out. Maybe citing something from over a decade ago isn't a great example of good C++ practice today.

Comment: Maybe an old practice is still good and I'm open to be convinced otherwise by a good argument other than ageism.

Comment: The fact that something works well is what *makes it* a "good practice. If the language changes such that it no longer works well, then it stop being a good practice.

Comment: Sure but perhaps, breaking something that works well is not a good idea.

Comment: Pre-C++11, `boost::get` as applied to an rvalue of a `boost::tuple` would have the *exact same problem*. `auto const& x = std::get<X>(boost::tuple<...>());` would cause the same dangling reference problem. So by your logic, we just shouldn't have tuples at all, or `get` shouldn't be able to work on an rvalue of a tuple? The latter would mean that we wouldn't be able to `get` from any `const&` of a tuple. Basically, the "rule" you're citing, even before C++11, was never as firm as you believe it was.

Comment: Your speculation about my logic is wrong. I never said that we should not have std::tuple and we should not be able to work on an rvalue tuple. My post says"I'd rather pay the price of the move" (so I agree with the comment by Mat on Vittorio's answer) ie I'd prefer if std::get returned by value and not by reference. I agree with you when you say that "Maybe citing something from over a decade ago isn't a great example of good C++ practice today" perhaps this applies to boost::get. Being old is almost irrelevant to me but some form of backward compatibility (including practices) is beneficial.